# How to get Assistant to look for music only on my phone

Tags: music-player, voice-command, google-assistant

I have about 60 gigs of music on my Samsung Galaxy S8.  I normally uses Pi Music Player, and am very happy with it.  But that's not so convenient while driving, so I'd like to control my music through Google Assistant.

However, when I ask Google assistant to say, "Play John Prine from my library", it's hit or miss whether it starts playing my John Prine collection or whether it offers up some random John Prine video from YouTube.  I can't seem to find any way to tell it reliably that I only want music from my phone.

I was about to buy a new car and enjoy the pleasures of Bluetooth voice commands so I don't have to fiddle with my phone while driving (my existing ten-year-old car does not offer me this option).  But it now appears that there's no way to do that; unless I pick up my phone and use the touch screen, the system is going to play whatever it feels like playing rather than the music that's right there on the phone.  I've put the car purchase on hold until I figure out whether there's a solution to this.  (I've also just spent an entire very frustrating day trying and failing to find settings I can adjust...)  Is there in fact a solution?

Comment: As you have music on device have you tried `play xxx on pi music player` as the ways to invoke an app from Google Assistant is limited. The phrase "my library" is too broad and as you've seen can invoke other apps. Related: https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/#media_actions

Comment: @MorrisonChang :  I have absolutely tried that ("play xxx on pi music player") about 17,000 times or so (because I never learn) and it makes absolutely no difference.  Sometimes it plays the music on my phone (without opening pi music player) and about half the time it brings up some marginally related youtube video instead.

Comment: Pi Music Player appears to support Youtube. Find one that doesn't, unless you've tried to disable that feature and the Assistant is bringing up the YouTube app. In my mind "Pi Music Player" isn't a unique enough app name for Assistant to not mishear a single syllable.

Comment: @MorrisonChang :  If I say "open pi music player", it opens pi music player every time, so it''s not mishearing.  It just doesn't play any music.  If I use the touch screen to start playing music in pi music player, then I can use google voice to say "next song", "previous song", "Pause", etc, and it all works great.  But I *can't* get it to switch to a different artist, album or playlist.  No matter how I try to word that request (and I've tried an unbelievable number of ways), the assistant just takes me right out of pi music player and starts offering youtube videos.

Comment: Hmm, assuming the authors of Pi Music Player did everything correctly, unfortunately when Assistant isn't behaving correctly there is little anyone can do other than sending feedback in the Assistant app.

Comment: @MorrisonChang:  I get exactly the same behavior with other music apps, so the problem is not with Pi.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by installing a different music player, namely Pulsar, which I believe is designed to play only local music.  I also did a bunch of other stuff, like disabling YouTube and uninstalling Google Play Music, which might or might not have contributed to the solution.   But Pi Music Player is still installed and the voice commands still fail to control it properly.

I (once only) told Google Assistant to "play Steve Goodman on Pulsar", it did what I asked, and ever since, it's been defaulting to Pulsar for all of my music requests, just as I wanted it to.  Following the exact same strategy with Pi Music Player does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: 1/3 Music - Bose QC Buds - Google's Assistant - Android Enthusiast Website

Solved the problem:

I'm using Samsung Music Player

I say, "Hey Google, Play Samsung Music "

And it worked

I shall have to split my answer into probably 3 posts because I will have to take more than 2,500 limit to properly deal with the topic.

1: Probably, the problem isn't what car you are driving, but the quality of the installed radio system, earbuds, earphones, headphones, and apps being used.

2: Google Assistant doesn't know what music player you want to use -unless you are inside the correct music player that you want to use, and also the music player will actually play the music and also is compatible with the Google's Assistant that are compatible with the latest voice commands.

3: If you weren't inside the correct music player - Google Assistant will probably have to guess, which place to go to, for example, to play the music requested.

4: I shall tell you how I managed to solve the problem eventually, but you should replace the things that I use with the ones that you use.

5: But I don't know if the things that you are using are good enough (have the latest software) for Google Assistant to take advantage of the voice recognition commands.

6: Make sure that you are using the latest updates with products.

7: Replace my items with the ones that you use.

8: I use the Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra phone  - You should replace it with your phone each time that I mention my phone, S20 Ultra.

9: I've got the latest Android 11 version that should be good enough  to operate Google Assistant voice.

10: I've got plenty of spare storage space on my phone, because as far as possible I save data onto my relatively fast read and write SanDisk Extreme Plus, V30 128GB, MicroSDXC Card inside my S20 Ultra's Phone (Ccleaner app may help to increase storage space).

11: I transferred data from my phone using Myfile that either came with my S20 Ultra's Phone or that I installed from Google's Playstore.

12: I then moved (cut and paste) data using Myfile inside my S20 to the SanDisk Extreme Plus 128GB MicroSDXC Card.

NB! (Note well)!

NB! If necessary used Samsung's (phone's) Technicians to solve any compatible problems with; Samsung Music Player, and Myfile, to allow Google Assistant to be able to automatically find all the relevant music, and play them.

I, shall check that commands work in 2 and 3.

Divide notes in Google's Doc App into half and hope that both halves are within the limit - copy and paste into this forum.

Hopefully, these 3 posts will help people to use voice commands within their products.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A site for Android end users and power users solving their issues. We appreciate your contribution here, but I'm afraid I'm having difficulty understanding some part of the answer due to [formatting issues](https://android.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and some txtspeak (what is "NB!" ?). Could you [edit] and fix them?

Comment: Thanks for improving the post! Perhaps it should be noted that Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a forum. "Answers" should be used for answering the question, not for posting a long discussion (consider taking a quick [tour] for a short introduction about this site). Also, just FYI, a single post can contain up to 30000 characters. You probably don't need to split it into multiple answers [unless the solutions are distinct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/241919).

Comment: Andrew, T, - Thanks for your help - Some people already gave curtailed (short) answers that still didn't solve the question. I prefer to provide a full answer that will solve any person's problem. - Any person who still doesn't understand can state why they don't understand, and the administrator can email me the website's page and I shall supply further infor. -   Editing was time consuming  - The limit was about 2,600 characters, and not 30,000 - Didn't have the option to edit - programming bug, Fault. - Hey Google Open Samsung Music stops the music, but may have to use right Bud to reboot